# Why does Vim force really long lines in text file?

Tags: editors, vim

I am using Vim to edit my tex file and I am relatively new to LaTeX. One thing that I don't understand is why tex wants you to write incredibly long lines in your tex file? For instance, each line becomes a new paragraph so if you have along paragraph you can have a line in your text file that is miles long. Currently this is driving me crazy because if I press 'j' or 'k' to move up and down lines I move lines at a time instead of paragraphs at a time.

While messing with this I just feel like "This can't be what I'm supposed to be doing." Does anyone else use an editor like vi/vim to edit their tex files, and if so, how do you navigate? If you are editing your .tex file full screen (to get rid of distractions), how do you prevent full monitor word garbage due to incredibly long lines?

I really like the TeX philosophy of separating content from design, but I feel like I am going to make myself go cross-eyed editing these .tex files.

Comment: TeX ignores single line breaks. Format your file however you want!

Comment: Only blank lines enforce a new paragraph. You can still use single linebreaks to structure your source.

Comment: @IanThompson better to say it treats single linebreaks like a space

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --- agreed.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of this. Is this how people typically compose their tex files? To use a end of line visual and press Return at the end? It seems to me that the obvious downfall of composing this way is if you delete parts of a line above, you need to manually delete the space to join two lines and then make a new line in a new place (if that makes sense). It seems like this method defeats the purpose of just typing and focusing on content.

Comment: @tomsrobots You could use an editor with overly-long-line-wrapping or, what I typically do, break the line after each sentence you type.

Comment: @HenriMenke The "one sentence per line" (the [third way](http://xkcd.com/1285/)) is particularly nice if you keep your .tex files under version control, since it makes diff-ing much easier.

Comment: In Vim `gq}` is your friend to reflow the current paragraph in a TeX source file (provided you have set `textwidth` to something sensible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can press return at the end, but in VIM you would typically "reformat" or "rewrap" a paragraph after and during writing. Typical commands to do so are:

```
gq (see :help gq)
gw (like gq but puts the cursor back where it started
:set textwidth = 70
```

`:set textwidth` is something people use for automatic wrapping, and sometimes it appears in their vimrc or plugin. I personally don't like it, and find that just rewrapping lines is much faster.

Once you get used to wrapping it becomes second nature while writing. I find that restyling the tex code is another way to find mistakes in the content or structure that I would not otherwise see.